# Python Regex - group match

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
details = '(2,5  cr / K / M)'
m = re.match(r'\((.*?)\w+cr\w/\w(.)\w/\w(.)\)', details)

credit = m.group(0)
state = m.group(1)
grade = m.group(2)


course = {'credit': credit, 'state': state, 'grade': grade}

print course
```

As this snippet shows, I want to get (`? cr / ? / ?`), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Note that `\w` is "word character" and not "white space." I think you mean `\s+` before 'cr.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks ilke you just confused w and s.. May not fit all edge cases:

```
import re

details = '(2,5  cr / K / M)'
pattern = re.compile(r'^\(([0-9],[0-9]).*/\s([A-Z])\s/\s([A-Z])\)')
m = pattern.match(details)

credit = m.group(1)
state = m.group(2)
grade = m.group(3)

course = {'credit': credit, 'state': state, 'grade': grade}

print course
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
m = re.match(r'\((.*?)\w+cr\w/\w(.)\w/\w(.)\)', details)
```

To:

```
m = re.match(r'\((\S+)\s+cr\s+/\s+(\S)\s+/\s+(\S)\)', details)
```

Where `\s` is "whitespace" and `\S` is "anything-but-whitespace".

Comment: Thank you very much! But I got {'grade': 'K', 'credit': '(2,5  cr / K / M)', 'state': '2,5'}, which should be {'grade': 'M', 'credit': '2,5', 'state': 'K'}

Comment: Note that group(0) is the entire match. You want groups 1,2,3 not 0,1,2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you saved me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\w[^\s)]*` and then remove any unwanted value:

```
>>> s = '(2,5  cr / K / M)'

>>> re.findall(r'\w[^\s)]*', s)
['2,5', 'cr', 'K', 'M']
```

Then you just need assign values discarding `cr` at index 1.

```
>>> s = '(2,5  cr / K / M)'
>>> out = re.findall(r'\w[^\s)]*', s)
>>> credit = out[0]
>>> state = out[2]
>>> grade = out[3]
>>> course = {'credit': credit, 'state': state, 'grade': grade}
>>> course
{'state': 'K', 'grade': 'M', 'credit': '2,5'}
```